# My title won't update

Tags: theme-options

No matter how many times I go into settings, and update my website title, it remains the same. And does not update? I've tried clearing my cache, uninstalling my old theme, searched through source files, and CANNOT figure out why - my title just won't update.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't update your low accept rate either. Anyways, have you tried checking your theme's header.php file? What is the value between the title tags?  Are you using any third party plugins for SEO like Wordpress SEO by Yoast? Try adding this between the title tags:

`<?php wp_title("",true); ?>`

You will also run into the issue of not having a page title if you are using a custom page as your homepage, the Wordpress Codex entry [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) for Wp_Title suggests this bit of code if that's the case:

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>`